# How to get only the number from a string?

Tags: php

I have strings like this:

> Lesson 001: Complete

I want to only get the number part, in this case `001`.

I tried this:

```
  $str = the_title();
  preg_match_all('!\d+!', $str, $matches);
  $number = implode(' ', $matches[0]);
  echo $number;
```

But `echo $number` outputs the entire string once again: `Lesson 001: Complete`

How to do this correctly?

Comment: your above query works

Comment: It outputs '001' without a problem.

Comment: yes it's working fine so what's your problem?

Comment: As I said to @ʰᵈˑ For some reason works if I do `$s = "Lesson 001: Complete";` but not when I do `$s = the_title();` Even though their ouput is the same. Not sure why.

Comment: @alexchenco Let me guess do: `var_dump(the_title());` and you will get `NULL`, right? You know why? [Because the function prints this, but doesn't return it!](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_title) **Solution ? use: get_the_title()** (100 points for me :)?)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

#### filter_var

You can use [`filter_var`](http://php.net/filter_var) and sanitize the string to only include integers.

```
$s = "Lesson 001: Complete";
echo filter_var($s, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
```

https://eval.in/309989

#### preg_match

You can use a regular expression to match only integers.

```
$s = "Lesson 001: Complete";
preg_match("/([0-9]+)/", $s, $matches);
echo $matches[1];
```

https://eval.in/309994

Comment: For some reason works if I do `$s = "Lesson 001: Complete";` but not when I do `$s = the_title();` Even though their ouput is the same. Weird.

Comment: @alexchenco see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29511413/how-to-get-only-the-number-from-a-string/29511466#comment47179172_29511413 (Rizier123 gets 100pts)

Comment: Note: FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT - removes all characters *except* digits, plus and minus sign.

Answer (score 2):

you can try with `/\d+/`

```
$str = the_title();
preg_match_all('/\d+/', $str, $matches);
echo $matches[0];
```