# Remove country code characters of a VAT string in PHP

Tags: php, regex

I need to remove some characters from a string in PHP
In the specific first I need to find the string below in a larger text,
and then remove the characters 'BG' from the string below:

```
<IdCodice>BG326325806</IdCodice>
```

basically the resulting string should be:

```
<IdCodice>326325806</IdCodice>
```

Now I know that with $re = '/[A-Z]{2}\d*/m';
I can match the string, but I don't know how to replace the original with the fixed string '326325806' in the text

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6278296/extract-numbers-from-a-string

Comment: You could match `<IdCodice>\K[A-Z]{2}` and replace with an empty string https://3v4l.org/8iLcK

Comment: or: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29511413/how-to-get-only-the-number-from-a-string

Comment: I found that this will solve my particular problem without affecting other parts in the electronic invoice: $str = preg_replace('/([A-Z]{2})(\d+)/', '$2', $str);